# Текст в окне подписки на RSS-ленту не переведён

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, rss

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12336

> Подписаться на ленту

https://ru.traducir.win/string/12331

> Для подписки на ленту скопируйте и вставьте ссылку из поля ниже в вашу RSS-читалку.